# Stuck on Automate The Boring Stuff Chapter 2- Continue Statement

Tags: python, while-loop, break, continue

I'm currently on Chapter 2 of Automate the Boring Stuff and am stuck on Continue Statement. The example given is if the name inputted is 'Joe' and the password is 'swordfish', the program would print 'Access granted'. However, I'm not sure why mine keeps printing 'Who are you?' when the condition for name = 'Joe' and password = 'swordfish' have already been fulfilled. Can anyone advise why I'm still stuck in the while-loop?

```
*while True:
    print('Who are you?')
    name = input()
    name = Joe
    if name != 'Joe':           #if name equal to 'Joe', print('Hello, Joe. What is the password? (It is a fish.)')
        continue                #if name not equal to 'Joe', continue executing while-loop
    print('Hello, Joe. What is the password? (It is a fish.)')
    password = swordfish
    if password == 'swordfish':    #if password equal to 'swordfish', exit the while-loop
        break                      #if password not equal to 'swordfish', execute the while-loop
print('Access granted.')*
```

Comment: The program has errors: `Joe` and `swordfish` are undefined. Did you mean `'Joe'` and `'swordfish'`?

Comment: Yes, 'Joe' and 'swordfish'. But I still get 'who are you?' printed even after setting them to strings

Comment: After I fix the error (and you should, too), the program works as expected. Please update the code ASAP and rerun it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are telling the function to continue after the `if` statement. So effectively `if name != 'Joe'` you want your function to `continue`, but if it is not, it's going to keep right on executing anyway.

There are other problems here that are going to cause you grief. You aren't actually using the variables defined by your `input()` and you aren't asking for user `input()` for the password.

To further simplify your code you can get rid of the continue statement altogether and just determine `if name == 'Joe'`. If it does, you can then ask for the password. Otherwise, the loop can continue. Here's a simplified solution:

```py
while True:
    name = input('Who are you?')
    if name == 'Joe':
        password = input('Hello, Joe. What is the password? (It is a fish.)')  
        if password == 'swordfish':
            print('Access granted.')
            break
```

Comment: Yes, it will keep doing that until you respond with `Joe`. Capitalization is important for your input too.

Comment: When you say 'respond with Joe', do you mean setting name = 'Joe' in line 2?

Comment: You should be running this program in the command line using `>>> python filename.py` where filename is the name you have saved your Python file under. Then you will be prompted with the question `Who are you?`, at which point you should type `Joe` to get the password question.

Comment: Gosh....thanks for pointing it out. I misunderstood the material and went to code the whole thing out when I'm supposed to run the program in the command line

Comment: No worries @MelissaSheu, it's how we all learn. If this works for you do me a solid and accept my answer by selecting the checkbox under the vote counter.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `print` when asking for the password, instead of `input`. Also note that you are assigning the variable `name` and `password` to a variable, instead of the string `'Joe'` and `'swordfish'`.

Here's a working example:

```
while True:
    name = input('Who are you?')
    if name != 'Joe':  # if name equal to 'Joe', print('Hello, Joe. What is the password? (It is a fish.)')
        continue  # if name not equal to 'Joe', continue executing while-loop
    password = input('Hello, Joe. What is the password? (It is a fish.)')
    if password == 'swordfish':  # if password equal to 'swordfish', exit the while-loop
        break  # if password not equal to 'swordfish', execute the while-loop

print('Access granted.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Joe and swordfish are not strings which causes a error. You have to add the quotes around them 'Joe' and 'swordfish'.

Comment: But even after setting quotes around 'Joe' and 'swordfish', the program still prints 'Who are you?'

Comment: I copied your code and ran it and it still prints 'Who are you?'